# Picking a PHP IDE and SVN package for professional software development?

Tags: software-development, php, ide, web-server, subversion

For the past few years I have been, in my spare time, completing freelance work. Most recently I have developed a piece of software that has picked up some interest and so I am going to be having it commercially distributing it.

My current setup has been simple as it has been all that I need, a simple WAMP like localhost / numerous VPS' for online deployment and debugging, and Notepad++ for editing/writing. However with the recent developments of interest in my software I am wanting to upgrade to a more professional 'workstation'.

I am looking, ideally, for a PHP IDE with integrated SVN control that can be stored locally (rather than external SVN storage - as a commercial product I need to keep all my side). There will be several versions of this software so if possible a way of sending some changes to all versions and other changes just to some.

If there is also a package for all of this that comes with a server setup (for Windows) I would be happy to change my localhost to this.

Any suggestions at this point are most appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "_integrated SVN control that can be stored locally_"?

Comment: @rrirower From what I understand some SVN systems store online/servers/FTPs/Github etc. I am just wanting a system to be able to store on my work computer rather than pushing files to elsewhere, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using [PHPED](http://www.nusphere.com/).  It's a PHP editor that provides debugging of local and remote systems and includes these features:

- Dynamic Syntax Highlighting
- Multiple Language Syntax Highlighting
- Auto Highlight Variable
- Code Folding
- Support for all HTML standards
- Fast Search
- Fast File Open
- Diff Viewer
- Worksets
- Bookmarks
- Code Profiler
- and more...

And, while it does not come installed with an SVN client, you can easily [integrate Tortoise SVN](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/technicalfaq/tip_phped_and_svn.htm) with PHPED.  SVN will allow you to set up a [local repository](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html) per your requirements.

PHPED is relatively inexpensive ($67 to $179 depending on the version), and can be installed on a trial basis.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks for this suggestion! Just what I am looking for.

Comment: To add. PHPED NuSphere interactive debugger has some features that xdebug doesn't. Like "set execution point" (or reverse debugging). Also it's easier to setup. I was used to debug in Visual Studio for C/C++, and PHPED was a perfect fit for PHP development and interactive debugging.

Answer (score 2):

[PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is exactly what you are looking for, even better. Also free for students, education and open source projects, else $89 /1st year, $71 /2nd year, $53 /3rd year onwards... If you are looking for a free IDE then go with [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). It also has local history.

Comment: There is nothing out there to beat PHPtorm (+1).  For those who want a free product, I recommend NetBeans, although you might also try out CodeLobster and even MS Visual Studio with its PHP extension